# Run two functions concurrently in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have the two functions below and I want them to run in parallel just like we use go routines in Go. Currently these do not run in parallel.

Please note that there is no async code in each of the functions, and I need to use returned data from both functions for later use.

Code:

```
import asyncio

async def func1(i: int) -> int:
    print("Initiated func1")
    while i <= 100000000:
        i += 1
    print("Finished func1")
    return 100

async def func2() -> (str, int):
    print("Initiated func2")
    return "hello world", 200

async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(*(func1(10), func2()))
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data1, data2 = asyncio.run(main())
    print(f"func1: {data1}, func2: {data2}")
```

Actual output:

```
Initiated func1
Finished func1
Initiated func2
func1: 100, func2: ('hello world', 200)
```

Expected output:

```
Initiated func1
Initiated func2
Finished func1
func1: 100, func2: ('hello world', 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

because, you declare func that is not awaitable.

```py
# sync code block in func1: not awaitable
while i <= 100000000:
    i += 1
```

add `asyncio.sleep(1)` in func or use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecuto`

```py
In [1]: import asyncio
   ...:
   ...: async def func1(i: int) -> int:
   ...:     print("Initiated func1")
   ...:     await asyncio.sleep(1)
   ...:     print("Finished func1")
   ...:     return 100
   ...:
   ...: async def func2() -> (str, int):
   ...:     print("Initiated func2")
   ...:     await asyncio.sleep(1)
   ...:     return "hello world", 200
   ...:
   ...: async def main():
   ...:     res = await asyncio.gather(*(func1(10), func2()))
   ...:     return res
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: await main()
Initiated func1
Initiated func2
Finished func1
Out[2]: [100, ('hello world', 200)]

In [3]: from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

In [4]: def func1(i: int) -> int:
   ...:     print("Initiated func1")
   ...:     while i <= 100000000:
   ...:         i += 1
   ...:     print("Finished func1")
   ...:     return 100
   ...:
   ...: def func2() -> (str, int):
   ...:     print("Initiated func2")
   ...:     return "hello world", 200
   ...:

In [5]: def main():
   ...:     with ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
   ...:         res = [pool.submit(func1, 10), pool.submit(func2)]
   ...:         return [res[0].result(), res[1].result()]
   ...:

In [6]: main()
Initiated func1
Initiated func2
Finished func1
Out[6]: [100, ('hello world', 200)]
```

Comment: thanks man! Are there any risks with this approach? Let's say func2 is making external api call so if the api call fails or timeout happens then what? @phi friday

Comment: There is also threading. Note: parrallel and concurently have different meaning and don't work in the same way. Choose which module you want according to your usecase. Multiprocessing use processes and can run on multiple CPU, asyncio and threading cannot for instance. Same, sharing data is not using the same mechanism etc.

Comment: What is executed in pool, is encapsulated in "concurrent.futures.Future".  there are many methods that can be checked whether "Future" has progressed normally, an error has occurred, or has been completed. However, since ProcessPoolExecutor is used, only pickable objects can be used as variables, and only pickable objects can be received as results. If you are focusing on IO operations, consider using ThreadPoolExecutor rather than ProcessPoolExecutor.

Answer (score -1):

You misunderstand how concurrency with `async`-functions works. It's nothing like go-routines. The asynchronous execution still happens **in one single thread**. The event loop just *may* switch execution whenever it encounters an `await`. This means, if you aren't doing I/O-bound tasks in your `async` functions, there will be no concurrency at all.

Even Threading will not help you in Python, but this has been discussed extensively on this platform (search for "GIL"). You can only achieve meaningful concurrency with your particular task with Python using multiprocessing.

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to deal with `async` functions at all. You can just use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module for this.

Comment: Several issues. go-routines are concurrency, a lot like co-routines. Co-routines are so if declared as ```async def``` not from the presence of an ```await``` inside, consider putting an item on a Queue for another co-routine. You've used concurrency both as commonly understood but also where I think you mean _no parallelism at all_.

Comment: Read my post again. I said concurrency with `async`-functions (i.e. coroutine functions) is "nothing like go-routines", and I stand by that. Go-routines can be moved to new threads by the OS. And that is principally different from coroutines in Python, which by default always run in one thread. I never said `await` makes coroutines concurrent. The presupposition was always that coroutines are concurrent. I said there will be no context switch without an `await`. The only point I agree with is that I should have written "no parallelism at all".

Comment: Read carefully before I commented, there is more than the one point wrong.

Comment: @jwal Well, that last one was not a very helpful comment. Please do enlighten us about what else was wrong.